# how to get specific text or number id in url with php

Tags: php

i need to get id from url like this
example

```
http://www.myweb.com/data/11111111111/show/2222222222?auth=c414-4a9a-a0ed-c5034dfdb379
```

how get `2222222222`

output

```
2222222222
```

with preg replace i try

```
$file = $a->url;
$file = preg_replace("/\".*\\\\(.*?)?");
echo $file ;
```

but not work

Comment: Is the id always going  to be after `/show/` you can search the string for that then take the value until you reach the question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number will be after `/show/` you can use this regex:

```
.+?\/show\/(\d+).*
```

as in this:

```
$file = $a->url;
$file = preg_replace("/.+?\\/show\\/(\\d+).*/", "$1", $file);
echo $file;
```

Note the `/` at the beginning and end of the regex. Those are called delimiters, and you need them. Also note that you have to escape the `\` characters by typing `\\`. And [`preg_replace()` takes a minimum of 3 parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), not 1.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rC6mU3/3)

Explanation:

- `.+?` matches any characters in a non-greedy fashion
- `\/show\/` matches `/show/`
- `(\d+)` matches any captures one or more digits
- `.*` any characters
- `$1` (in the replacement) replace with the captured group

---

If you can't rely on `/show/` being there and just want the second number that appears, change the regex to this:

```
https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/\D+\d+\D+\/(\d+).*
```

So your code becomes:

```
$file = $a->url;
$file = preg_replace("/https?:\\/\\/[^\\/]+\\/\\D+\\d+\\D+\\/(\\d+).*/", "$1", $file);
echo $file;
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tE5mS3/3)

Explanation:

- `http` match `http
- `s?` optional `s`
- `:\/\/` match `://`
- `[^\/]+` one or more non-`/` characters
- `\/` match `/`
- `\D+` one or more non-digit characters
- `\d+` one or more digits (so, the first number)
- `\D+` one or more non-digit characters
- `\/` match `/`
- `(\d+)` match and capture one or more digits (the second number)
- `.*` any characters
- `$1` (in the replacement) replace with the captured group

Comment: @vallez Glad to help!